# Need MYSQL Query to select specific child rows only

Tags: mysql

FX., Given tables for baskets and fruits, looking for a query that returns the basket_id that contains **ONLY** the two specific fruit.

EX
table: fruits

```
basket_id | fruit
_________________
1         | apple
1         | orange
1         | pear

2         | apple
2         | orange

3         | apple
3         | pear
```

Given the above table, I'm looking for a query that returns the basket_id that **ONLY** contains the fruits "apple" and "orange", which would be row 2 only. Basket id 1 should be excluded because it also contains "pear".

Help with this would be most appreciated.

Comment: why not basket 3 also this basket_id has also two specific fruits?

Comment: second row only means? would you include first entry of apple and orange?

Answer (score 2):

Please note for the example table, I added one more basket which is basket_id = 4, that has two apples only, and it will be a strong test sample for the query.

```
WITH ABC  --sample table
AS
(
SELECT 1 as basket_id, 'Apple' as fruit
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 as basket_id, 'Orange' as fruit
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 as basket_id, 'Pear' as fruit
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 as basket_id, 'Apple' as fruit
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 as basket_id, 'Orange' as fruit
UNION ALL 
SELECT 3 as basket_id, 'Apple' as fruit
UNION ALL 
SELECT 3 as basket_id, 'Pear' as fruit
UNION ALL 
SELECT 4 as basket_id, 'Apple' as fruit
UNION ALL 
SELECT 4 as basket_id, 'Apple' as fruit
)
 --main query:   
SELECT basket_id FROM
(
 SELECT *,CASE WHEN fruit in ('Apple','Orange') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS row_check
 FROM ABC
 ) as A
GROUP BY basket_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT row_check) =1 -- make sure there is no other fruit 
AND COUNT(DISTINCT fruit) >1   -- make sure there are at least one apple and one orange
```

> output: basket_id 2

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  f.basket_id,
  (select count(1) from fruits where basket_id = f.basket_id) as fruits_in_basket,
  (select count(1) from fruits where basket_id = f.basket_id and fruit in ("apple", "orange")) as specific_fruits_in_basket
from
  fruits as f
group by f.basket_id
having fruits_in_basket = specific_fruits_in_basket
```

Here is a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4ae3c/37/0

Comment: if basket 3 has only two apples, basket 3 will be returned as well, which is what op wants.

Comment: @LONG Actually, no. I'm looking for a basket with exactly those two fruit. No more, no less.

Comment: if basket 3 does not have orange but two apples,  it will still be returned

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT basket_id 
FROM fruits f
WHERE 
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM fruits f1 WHERE f.basket_id=f1.basket_id AND f1.fruit NOT IN ('apple', 'orange'))
AND
   (SELECT count(*) FROM fruits f2 WHERE f.basket_id=f2.basket_id AND f2.fruit='apple')=1
AND 
   (SELECT count(*) FROM fruits f3 WHERE f.basket_id=f3.basket_id AND f3.fruit='orange')=1;
```

I have tested the query on your example. [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4ae3c/50)

Comment: Don't know why you downvoting this answer guys. The query is 100% ok. Please explain whats wrong...

Comment: I did not downvote but if there is a basket has only apples, it will returned as well, which is not what op wants.

Comment: maybe you need to update your Demo as well, nice answer, upvote :)

Comment: @LONG I have updated Demo. thanks a lot of your comments. looks like there is no way without counting the rows. so your answer is very useful and must be accepted.

Comment: Thank you @vadim_hr:) So far I do not have any better solution to this answer, both sharing the learning xD

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to use the list of items as an ordered list you want to select like `'apple,orange'`, then you can use following.

```
SELECT f.basket_id, f.fruit
FROM fruits f
     INNER JOIN (
         SELECT basket_id, GROUP_CONCAT(fruit order by fruit) as a
         FROM fruits
         GROUP BY basket_id
         HAVING a = 'apple,orange'
     ) f1 ON f.basket_id = f1.basket_id
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4ae3c/47).

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(basket_id) 
FROM basket
where fruit IN ('apple', 'orange');
```